# ZURB Foundation: Same size form selects and inputs

Tags: css, html, zurb-foundation

I'm starting to use zurb foundation and would like to know what the "foundation way" of sizing inputs and selects is.

Basically i got row with four columns and in each one a form element.
By default every element has a different height.

**Please refer to this screenshot i took:**
[image: http://i.imgur.com/dpWZLq1.png]

So again, what would be the zurb foundation way to size the elements evenly?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not sure what you mean, surely you should just size the heights using standard CSS to fit whatever design you're using.

Comment: yeah i think so but i'm curious about best practice to learn from. bootstrap for instance sizes them by default evenly.

Comment: You can add the `custom` class to your form and the textbox and dropdown will be of the same size. The button will not follow the same height though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this Foundation form mixin: [form-element](https://github.com/zurb/foundation/blob/master/scss/foundation/components/_forms.scss#L93)

If you are using SASS, you can do something like this:

**your_styles_file.css.scss**

```
select {
  @include form-element;
}
```

Doing so, you'll have all form inputs and selects with the same look and feel.

Beware of the width property set by this mixin, which is 100%.